# Avoid geting cached results from the browser in an autocomplet field

Tags: ajax

I need some help on a autocomplet function using ajax
 My problem is : the browser is caching the suggestions from ajax  when i press enter on a suggestion, so the next time I'm typing in the suggestion field, i get de value from the cach

Here is the part of the Ajax code through which I send a value to the php code and get the respondsetext

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","**suggest.php**?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

and the input tag

input id="valx" onKeyUp="autocomplet(this.value)"

Example: I type in the input field "Htm" and I get the suggestions "Html","HTML CSS" , "HTML XMLS" .... so if I chose "HTML CSS" and press enter, the next time I type "Htm" in the input field the browser shows the cached value => "HTML CSS" an of course I also have my suggestions send by ajax Html","HTML CSS" , "HTML XMLS" .....  I want to get rid of the cached values send by the browser

I saw a tutorial for my problem but I dont know how to apply it to my code because I"m already sending a request through "q". 
The cod from the tutorial looks like this

xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.php?t=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
 it is using the random method to send different data request each time ??

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser is interfering with your AJAX-y autocomplete, try setting `autocomplete="off"` on the input element.

Comment: this is the input   <input onKeyUp="autocomplet(this.value)" />   how should I set autocomplet="off" in this input. I don't understand your idee

Comment: @soso `<input autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="autocomplet(this.value)" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="myField" .... autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="autocomplet(this.value)">
```